# How to display post title and link within wp_list_categories()

Tags: categories

I'm testing something which needs to display posts within `wp_list_categories()`. Basically I want to display all content for a taxonomy.

I'm pretty sure that to make it happen I have to alter the WP class or function that handles categories and stuffs like this. Is that the way?

**EDIT:** I've opened the core file that contains `wp_list_categories()`. It's in `wp_includes` in the file called `category-template.php`

How can I alter this?

**EDIT 2:** there's a filter `wp_list_categories`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you can achieve the desired effect in two different ways.

### Extend the Category Walker

Extend [the `Walker_Category()` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Category) and overwrite the `start_el()` method with similar code that retrieves a list of posts in the category being processed and displays them in an unordered list within the category's `<li>` element. To use your new walker class, pass it's name in the `walker` argument of `wp_list_categories()`.

### Procedurally Process Cateogries

Rather than having `wp_list_categories()` echo out a list of categories, set the `echo` argument to `false`, set a variable to the function call's return value, and use the PHP regular expression and string functions to modify the markup as needed.

The second solution can alternately be achieved by hooking into the `wp_list_categories` filter, which receives the same generated markup as an argument that `wp_list_categories()` returns when `echo` is set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to be sure. I'm gonna go with procedural in this case ^^

Comment: Sure thing! Tricky part about the procedural approach is that you'll have to figure out how to extract the term from the list-item so that you can query it for posts (I'm not positive, but I think that the `term_id` may be the number appended to the `cat-item-{number}` CSS class). When extending the `Walker_Category` class, the `term_id` is immediately available in the `start_el()` method in the form of the `$id` argument.

Comment: yeah but it's deprecated.

Comment: Huh... good catch!! It's not deprecated, but it's definitely not used - looks like that's just there to properly extend the `Walker` class. Annoying that it's not marked as unused. But the `term_id` is still available via `$category->term_id`.

Comment: I finally get through this with 1rst method XD. Thanks again.